# GitHub Actions generated docker image results in "Permission denied" when running the image

Tags: docker, rust, github-actions

I wanted to experiment with GitHub Actions: compiling a cargo project, building a docker image and publishing it as a GitHub package (the Project can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/mobergmann/actions-docker-test/tree/main)). It worked, the Rust project gets compiled, the docker image gets build and the image is then published. But when I try to run the image I get the following respone:

```
mobergmann@ziegel ~> docker pull ghcr.io/mobergmann/actions-docker-test:latest
Trying to pull ghcr.io/mobergmann/actions-docker-test:latest...
... # rest is left out, because of redundancy
mobergmann@ziegel ~> docker run ghcr.io/mobergmann/actions-docker-test:latest
/bin/sh: 1: ./gh-action-test: Permission denied
```

Permission denied when running the compiled binary. I can't wrap my head around that, especially because in the Dockerfile I do:

```
RUN chmod 555 gh-action-test
RUN ls -l .
RUN ls -l gh-action-test
```

And the output in my Actions log is:

```
#7 [2/7] COPY ./target/release/gh-action-test /src/gh-action-test
#7 DONE 0.0s

#8 [3/7] WORKDIR /src
#8 DONE 0.0s

#9 [4/7] RUN pwd
#9 0.224 /src
#9 DONE 0.2s

#10 [5/7] RUN chmod 555 gh-action-test
#10 DONE 0.3s

#11 [6/7] RUN ls -l .
#11 0.322 total 4
#11 0.322 dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Oct 30 22:19 gh-action-test
#11 DONE 0.3s

#12 [7/7] RUN ls -l gh-action-test
#12 0.209 total 4548
#12 0.209 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4654808 Oct 30 22:19 gh-action-test
#12 DONE 0.2s
```

Why are the file rights different for `ls -l .` and `ls -l <file>`?

---

When I try to compile and build the image locally I don't get the error when running the image. I suspect that the error ist due to the artifacts, but I'm not sure.
Can anyone of you help me figure out how to make the form the Actions generated image executable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `gh-action-test` **directory** in which there is a `gh-action-test` file, that's what the `d` in `dr-xr-xr-x` stands for. The `ls -l .` command shows the `gh-action-test` directory which is inside the current directory. The `ls -l gh-action-test` command shows the `gh-action-test/gh-action-test` file.

If you do `ls -ld gh-action-test`, you should see the same permissions as in `ls -l .`